# How to get attribute of href on the basis of selected text?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex, preg-match

I have a link like this one

```
<a href="site.com/register.php?mid=username&mode=bn&bid=1">
```

Now i need to get value of mid or bid on the basis of

```
site.com/register.php
```

in a page. and need to do in javascript. http is also there.

How to do that.

Thank you.

Comment: JS or PHP? Which one? Either case, just use the HTML parser/DOM built in.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: The link is incorrect, unless you really want to relatively link to `http://www.example.com/site.com/register.php?mid=username&mode=bn&bid=1` when linking from `http://www.example.com/`.

Comment: I have used getAttribute but couldn't find the way to match  site.com/register.php

Comment: try this `[^"]+(?=\?)` or `<a href="([^"]+)`

Comment: when do you need this?  Do you want after you have clicked that link or during the html page is being loaded?  It's unclear on how you are executing this part

Comment: @Pavel Šimerda. no not like that, you didn't get me. i just want to get a particular link value on the basis of text which i put in code.

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't get *me*. I was just pointing out that the link in your example is most probably wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

put id for anchor tag

```
<a id="anchor1" href="site.com/register.php?mid=username&mode=bn&bid=1">
```

use below javascript

```
<script>
 var href = document.getElementById('anchor1').href;
 //get index of ?
 var indexStart = href.indexOf('?');
 var indexLast = href.length;
 //get href from ? upto total length
 var params = href.substring(indexStart+1, indexLast);
 //get tokens with seperator as '&' and iterate it
 var paramsArray = params.split("&");
 for(var i=0;i<paramsArray.length;i++)
 {
   //get key and value pair
   var paramKeyValue = paramsArray[i];
   var keyValue = paramKeyValue.split('=');
   alert("Key="+keyValue[0]+" and value="+keyValue[1]);
 }
</script>
```

**[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/7La9u8p8/17/)**

Comment: value is not coming in href.

Comment: i am using only var href = document.getElementById("anchor1").href;
 alert(href);

Comment: and console response  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of null .... i have provided id same id to anchor tag.

Comment: I have missed closing bracket in for loop, now corrected. this is the demo link http://jsfiddle.net/7La9u8p8/16/

Comment: i think  var href = document.getElementById("anchor1").href; alert(href); is not use anymore as my editor dreamweaver is not supporting it also there is no alert is showing with this.

Comment: your example is working fine if i use jquery, but i want to use with pure javascript, once i remove jquery in your code, it fail to give alert.

Comment: Now i have done it with your code. thank you.

Comment: actually I was not able to put javascript code as it is in jsfiddle hence added a button click event. I am glad that it is working for you :)

Answer (score -1):

```
var Links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

var Values = {}; 

for(var i = 0; i < Links.length; i++) { 
    if(Links[i].href.toString().indexOf('site.com/register.php') != -1) {

        var Str = Links[i].href.toString();
        var Arr = Str.split('?');
        Arr[1] = Arr[1] || '';

        var Params = Arr[1].split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < Params.length; i++) {
            var Value = Params[i].split('=');
            Values[Value[0]] = Value[1] || null;
        }
        break;
    }
}

console.log(Values);
```

Comment: yes that is the thing which i'll do later, but first i need to find that site.com/register.php among several links in a page.

Comment: Try this edited answer

Comment: empty values are coming in console... i have used your same codes...but its not working.